# How to remove a particular child value from Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is my firebase model and I want to delete 
"specific message node" from my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvPAU.png)

// there is notification coming from firebase and it is getting update in table view but there is one specific notification which I don't want to show it on table view, I just want to handle that notification in viewDidLoad so I can delete when it comes

```
`objRef.child("notification_user").child(MyCurrentUSERID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0{
                let allLocationData = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                var mainArr :[AnyObject] = []
                for item in  allLocationData{

                    let obj = item.value! as! NSDictionary
                    obj.setValue(item.key, forKey: "autoId")
                    mainArr.append(obj as AnyObject)
                }
                let data = Mapper<NotificationModel>().mapArray(JSONObject: mainArr)
                completion(true, data, nil) }`
```

// this is snapshot coming from firebase and i want to delete snapshot which contain message "group clicked"

```
{
    action = 3;
    autoId = "-LoOhMMELiTD1Qpx7nNH";
    body = Office;
    isChecked = 0;
    message = "Congratulations! You've been added successfully in Office";
    newMessage = "Congratulations! You've been added successfully in ##";
    receiverID =     (
        LcyvJLDTT1g82CWqXs6YC0XwoEf1
    );
    roomId = 1505182734;
    senderId = 8mvL2JG4alevQfK01fO6OrWs6a33;
    thumbnail = "";
    timestamp = 1568094385768;
    title = Office;
}, {
    action = 106;
    autoId = "-LoPA3Q4Quji42y7yNBp";
    body = "wakeup iOS device";
    isChecked = 0;
    message = "group clicked";
    newMessage = "group clicked";
    receiverID =     (
        LcyvJLDTT1g82CWqXs6YC0XwoEf1
    );
    roomId = 1505182734;
    senderId = 8mvL2JG4alevQfK01fO6OrWs6a33;
    thumbnail = "";
    timestamp = 1568102172213;
    title = "wakeup iOS device";
}
```

Comment: Explain your issue in text and also post the code that is relevant to your issue.

Comment: extended info is there, do you have answer ?. Thanks for your view by the way.

Comment: Are you asking how to delete the node where newMessage = "group clicked"? If so what kind of difficulties are you having doing that? Can you show the code you're attempting to use to delete that node?

Comment: objRef.child("notification_user").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
   print("snapshot empty")
  }
  // Access the message
  if data["message"] != nil && data["message"] == "group clicked" {
     objRef.child("notification_user").child(MyCurrentUSERID).child(snapshot.key).removeValue()
  }
})

Comment: This code note working even, I want to delete whole node which consist message "group clicked"

Answer (score 1):

> Delete data
>
> The simplest way to delete data is to call `removeValue` on a reference
>   to the location of that data.
>
> You can also delete by specifying nil as the value for another write
>   operation such as setValue or updateChildValues. You can use this
>   technique with updateChildValues to delete multiple children in a
>   single API call.

```
objRef.child("notification_user").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
   print("snapshot empty")
  }
  // Access the message
  if data["message"] != nil && data["message"] == "group clicked" {
     objRef.child("notification_user").child(MyCurrentUSERID).child(snapshot.key).removeValue()
  }

})
```

Comment: Sir, is there many way I can delete whole node who has message "group clicked" in it? If I will delete whole node then only it won't get update in my table view, eg-: there are two node given above, I want to delete second one because it contain message "group clicked"

Comment: This deletes the whole snapshot

Comment: I want to delete only a node which contain this message beside we can't compare data["message"] == "group clicked" one is Any type and another one is String type